# Is it unsafe for the javascript client to set the CSRF token?

Tags: javascript, security, csrf, websecurity

It seems to me that the primary goal of CSRF is to confirm that the client making the request is the client we expect.

The solution I've commonly seen is:

1. Server generates random CSRF Token
2. Server sets CSRF token in cookie
3. 1. Server injects the CSRF token into the form when generating the form
      OR
   2. Server passes the CSRF token to javascript and javascript injects the CSRF token as a header on XMLHTTPRequests
4. When a request is received, it's validated by checking that the CSRF token in the cookie matches the CSRF token in header/form value.

It makes a lot of sense to me that the server is generating the CSRF for (3)(1), but I cannot come up with a reason why it's necessary for (3)(2).

Instead, if the client is pure javascript, I believe this is safe:

1. Javascript generates a random CSRF token
2. Javascript sets the CSRF token in a cookie
3. Javascript passes the CSRF token in the header when making an XMLHTTPRequest
4. Server checks that CSRF token in the header and cookie match

My understanding is that 3 and 4 are both things an attacker cannot do, so this would also sufficiently block attacks.  Is that correct?

If that *is* safe, do we even need to do step (1) and (2)?  Would this be safe as well because of same-origin policy (assuming cors is configured properly)?

1. Javascript sets an 'CSRF-Safe: true' header in XMLHTTPRequest
2. Server checks that the header CSRF-Safe exists and is set to "true"

Comment: Why do you think an attacker cant do 1 to 4 and beyond? Most attackers wont even use your code, and will craft the request to suit the vulnerability, in your case just set both header and cookie to some random value to bypass the check.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, but if they did, couldn't they generate a known code and use it for (1) and (2)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have unique session cookies to authorize the request, as well.  I believe CSRF is just to validate the client, when the client is a browser.  Mobile app code doesn't need to do CSRF checking, to my knowledge.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, I think my question made me realize we're on the same page. I was just addressing your unedited comment about (1) and (2).

Comment: CSRF is to prevent logged in user doing some action against their knowledge either by mitm replay or some xss code which has got through.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I think XSS and CSRF are different classes of attacks, and I don't expect CSRF tokens to prevent XSS attacks.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting - It's definitely possible though that server-generated CSRF tokens also protect against some class of XSS vulnerabilities I'm not thinking of.  Are you aware of any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both of those simplified approaches should be safe in the presence of CORS and the same-origin policy. In fact, you don't even need the `CSRF-Safe: true` header as long as you validate the content-type.

Wikipedia [confirms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#HTTP_verbs_and_CSRF):

> If data is sent in any other format (JSON, XML) a standard method is to issue a POST request using XMLHttpRequest with CSRF attacks prevented by SOP and CORS; there is a technique to send arbitrary content from a simple HTML form using ENCTYPE attribute; such a fake request can be distinguished from legitimate ones by text/plain content type, but if this is not enforced on the server, CSRF can be executed[12][13]